# How to remove extra path from img src by jquery

Tags: jquery

now i am getting that path in img src

```
<img alt="test" src="http://www.wsoradio.com/wp-content/uploads/http://www.wsoradio.com/wp-content/files/acbreviews/a4/B001THPA4Y/smallimage.jpg">
```

but i need output

```
<img alt="test" src="http://www.wsoradio.com/wp-content/files/acbreviews/a4/B001THPA4Y/smallimage.jpg">
```

i want to remove this extra path from  img src before http://www.wsoradio.com/wp-content/files/acbreviews/a4/B001THPA4Y/smallimage.jpg by jquery

```
http://www.wsoradio.com/wp-content/uploads/  (want to remove it)
```

plz guide me how to do it, thanks

Comment: Don't do this using jQuery, don't even do it with javascript. Fix the server-side issue with the URL generation.

Comment: @vikastyagi: what plugin? Fix the plugin. Seriously, if you try to patch over this with jQuery, you're just fixing the problem temporarily and, by introducing extra complexity, storing up bigger problems for the future.

Comment: @vikastyagi: if the plugin is open-source, and you post the details, someone here will be able to fix it for you

Answer (score 1):

you shouldnt have 2 urls together but if you insist :

```
$("img ").attr("src",$("img ").attr("src").split('http://www.wsoradio.com/wp-content/uploads/')[1])
```

Comment: Note that, for this very kind of situation, `.attr()` can be passed a callback function which will receive the current value of whatever attribute you're setting. Very useful - you don't need to explicitly fetch the value. I.e. `$('img').attr('src', function(index, value) { return value.split('...'); });`

Comment: @BobbyJack nice...didnt know that.

Comment: lots of similar jQuery methods support this, including `.css()`. It's very useful and, once you start using it, you'll never go back :)

Comment: @vikastyagi you didnt had any ID so i continued with your example.... if you have ID so change to : $("#myImgId")